# How to hide TclTk window in R while it is being drawn

Tags: r

TclTk is working fine in R, it's just that I can see the widgets being placed on the window as it is being built. Is there a way to hide the window, and only show it once it is built? Paste the following into R and you'll see the window filling up. That's what I don't want user to see (if possible). Thanks.

```
require(tcltk)
dlg = tktoplevel()
# command to hide window ?
for (i in 1:10) {
    l = list()
    for (i in 1:20) l[[i]]=tkbutton(dlg,text="SO")
    do.call(tkgrid,l)
}
# command to show window now it is built ?
tkwait.window(dlg)
tkdestroy(dlg)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the following pattern in gWidgetstcltk:

```
library(tcltk)
tclServiceMode(FALSE)
win <- tktoplevel()
tkwm.state(win,"withdrawn") 
tclServiceMode(TRUE)

## ... do your thing then:
tkwm.state(win,"normal")
```

Comment: Thank you!! tclServiceMode() works perfectly, didn't need the calls to tkwm.state(). As a bonus the window also appears instantly now, from which I conclude that a window redraw after each widget is added is quite expensive (rather than TclTk itself per se).

Answer (score 2):

You can just wrap the whole thing in curly braces. That's worked for me so far.

Something like:

```
{ # Begin building window
  (code)
} # End building window
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Next time I need to do this I'll definitely give it a go.